# How Can I See All Laravel Events Being Fired

Tags: laravel

How can I see all laravel events being fired or search for events that are specific to my use case. I should be able to see a list of events being fired during a single request.

Answer (score 2):

you can install Laravel DebugBar: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

and then on the `config/debugbar.php`

```
'collectors' => [
    <snip>
    'events' => true,
    <snip>
];
```

you should then see a bar at the bottom page of your app:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Within a service provider modify your boot method to include the following. The "*" can be modified to filter events. Once you know the full name of the event you can enter it instead.

```
 public function boot(Dispatcher $events)
    {
        $events->listen('*', function ($model) {
            var_dump(Event::firing());
        });
    }
```