# To prevent timeout - what are the advantages of queueing a job vs chunking results?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My Laravel 5 site allows users to send emails to their contacts.  My problem is that the operation times out after it loops through around 50 contacts.

An overview of my process:

- Get the list of contacts
- Construct an email
- Loop through the list of contacts and send them each an email using a mailer service.
- return email details to the controller to be saved in the db.

Chunking is pretty easy to understand, but I'm not real comfortable with the mechanics of placing a job on a queue.

To prevent the timeout, would I be better off chunking the contacts to limit the size of the loop or putting the entire job on a queue?   If the entire job should be placed on a queue - can I still chunk contacts?   Can a queued job still use mail::queue or is that just redundant?

Loop Code:

```
public function sendIndividualEmail($members, $subject, $body, $file)
   {

     $view  = 'emails.memberMessage';

     //construct email details
     $mData = $this->emailConstructor($subject, $body);

     //check to see if there is an attachment, if so upload it.
     if (!is_null($file)){
            $uploadedFile = $this->attachment->saveAttachment($file);

            $mData['path'] = 'https://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/uploads/attachments/'.$uploadedFile['filename'];
            $mData['display'] = $uploadedFile['display'];
        }


     foreach($members as $member){

                if (!empty($member->contact_email)){

                  //add member details here
                    $mData['email'] = $member->contact_email;
                    $mData['name'] = $member->contact_firstName;

                   //email member
                    $this->emailTo($view, $mData);
                    $mData['emailCount']++;
                }           

    }
    return $mData;
}
```

Mailer Service:

```
public function emailTo($view, $mData)
 {

    Mail::queue($view, $mData, function($message) use ($mData)
    {
      $message->from($mData['from'], $mData['fromName']);
      $message->to($mData['email'], $mData['name'])->subject($mData['subject']);
      $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MC-Metadata', $mData['meta']);
        if(array_key_exists('path', $mData)){
            $message->attach($mData['path'], array('as' => $mData['display']));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions first.
Chunking them would use less computational power, but does not offer the flexibility that a queue system presents.

Chunking scenario ---
Get All Models, for count(x) as new chunk store chunk.
Foreach chunk as items
foreach item in items
item->doSomething

-- Pagination
I might adapt the pagination library to support this instead.
I.E get a collection and paginate it, store the page number, and just do a page worth of records at a time?

-- Event Observer Queue?
Another technique would be to use the event listener system.
You can to this a number of ways, just think about when an email should be sent.

Your model would have either a column like sent_mymail_email, or you could use a mutator getSentMymailEmailAttribute() to return a boolean value of true if the email was sent (job is complete).

You would then set up a new event or latch on to an existing event.

see: [How Can I See All Laravel Events Being Fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858837/how-can-i-see-all-laravel-events-being-fired)

Queue system -- 
A queue system would receive events and data from one server via http request . The items are then added to a big list of jobs that need to be completed. When the event comes up (it's turn), it will send a http request to somewhere on your system. Your system then interprets what the task is and accomplishes the task, when complete, a response is sent back to the queue system(typically) notifying the system of a completed task. The queue will then move on to the next task, send the request ... and so on.

Comparing this to the chunk method, you can see that your application needs to send the email in both scenarios, however it does not need to send the task, receive the task or interpret what the task is in the chunking method.

You also have less moving parts in the chunking method, however if you wanted the ability to scale and put part of your applications workload onto a secondary system or cluster to handle the jobs, you would want to go with the queue system.

The queue system depends on 3rd party services that have their own built in flaws. For example you cant define an order for these items.

This blog post explains: 
http://cloudstacking.com/posts/amazon-sqs-gotchas.html

Here is another decent post about using queue systems:
http://www.isixsigma.com/industries/retail/queuing-theory-and-practice-source-competitive-advantage/

The advantage in a nutshell primarily being that you have the ability to scale to a very large amount of these requests being processed with zero impact on your front-end(application).

You can run these jobs on a separate system or cluster of systems to push the work that is needed to a server that does not impact user experience.

Comment: I think setting up the queue is what I'm interested in doing.   Thank you for the great explanation.

Comment: Great explanation, It directed me to a couple of ways I could do other things in my App

Answer (score 0):

You are able to queue the entire job and still queue the mail, I do that in my application and don't feel it is redundant. It allows you to break up the processing into logical steps that can be completed independent of one another. For example the job can continue processing the contacts and scheduling the emails without needing to wait for them to send.

While I haven't done it myself, I believe you are able to chunk the contacts and still use a queue on the job.